# The loop is not ending, and I need to find the error in the code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int64_t n;
    int64_t m;
    int64_t Sum;
    cin >> n;
    for(int64_t i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        int64_t a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        int64_t m = 0;
        while(m <= b){
            int64_t y = 0;
            m = a + y;
            Sum += m;
            y++;
        }
    }
    cout << Sum;
}
```

When I run the above code in the compiler, the loop is not ending and I am keeping entering the values.

Comment: In the `while` loop `y` is fixed to `0`, so `m` never changes (`m == a`), also `b` never changes, ergo if the loop starts it will never stop

Comment: Just move `int64_t y=0;` outside the loop.

Comment: Try to find a video tutorial for your IDE that teaches you how to step through code with a debugger. Also, autoformat the code, it makes it easier to read, understand and get right. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
while(m<=b){
     int64_t y=0;
     m=a+y;
     Sum +=m;
     y++;
 }
```

There's `int64_t y = 0` which will make a new `y` equal to 0 in every single iteration. `y++` is useless, and so `m = a + y` will be the same as `m = a + 0` which will never change the value of `m` and the boolean `m <= b` will always be true. Do this:

```
int64_t y = 0;
while(m<=b){
     m=a+y;
     Sum +=m;
     y++;
 }
```

Here, `int64_t y = 0` will only be executed once and `y` won't be reset, so the loop will terminate.